# How to avoid leaving browsing history in router logs?

Tags: firefox, router, privacy

I'm using Firefox 3.6.8 and I've seen that you can browse privately with it. But if I do that, I can see that websites still register in my router logs. I'm using a Netgear router and if I check the logs I can still the sites that I visited.

Is there a way where you can surf totally without leaving the history of the sites that you visited?

Comment: private browsing can be less than private - http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-10891355

Comment: Agree with @bryan (+1). Flash cookies (not explicitly mentioned in the linked BBC article) are also a problem with _private_ browsing - in that they are not removed afterwards. However, I think the latest versions of some browsers together with the latest version of Flash might now be OK?

Comment: The Better Privacy addon will clear these flash cookies. you can set to clear them on exit of firefox. https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/6623/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Private mode just tells the browser not to keep history, cookies, and the like.  It's not an anonymous proxy.

The only way to do what you want is to find a proxy server on the Internet that you trust to act as an anonymous proxy server.  Your router will still record that you went to that server, though.  There's not much you can do about that.

Comment: @tintincute: Tor.